# Elastic Monitoring Infrastructure - Blank Fields in Metrics

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, metricbeat

I'm populating the Elasticsearch Infrastructure Monitoring app, and some of the fields are blank in metrics such as Instance ID, Cloud Provider, Machine Type, and Availability Zone. I already overwrite the cloud.* fields in metricbeat by adding this:

```
fields_under_root : true
fields:
  cloud.provider : "TEST"
  cloud.availability_zone : "TEST"
  cloud.machine.type : "TEST"
```

The value is searchable in discover logs, But nothing change on metrics in the image shown below. Is there any way to add custom value in this field without using a cloud provider like AWS?

[image: Blank fiels]

Here is the version of the ELK Stack.

**Kibana Version 7.5.1 

Elasticsearch Version 7.5.1 

Filebeat Version 7.5.1**

Answer (score 0):

Those fields are not fields that you add manually in the `fields` section (since they will land into the `fields` hash), it's not what you want and it's not where that dashboard sources those values.

What you need to do is simply enable the [`add-cloud-metadata` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/add-cloud-metadata.html) in your metricbeat configuration:

Add this to your metricbeat.yml configuration file, restart metricbeat and you'll see the values auto-magincally appear on the dashboard:

```
processors:
- add_cloud_metadata: ~
```

**UPDATE:**

If that's the case and nothing gets added to those fields, what I suggest to do is to use the `add_fields` processor after the `add_cloud_metadata` one so as to override them:

```
processors:
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_fields:
      target: '' # add fields at top-level
      fields:
        cloud.provider : "TEST"
        cloud.availability_zone : "TEST"
        cloud.machine.type : "TEST"
```

Comment: I already added the that in the processors what I mean in my questions is if I can customize those data from filebeat and it will appear in the picture above?

Comment: Ive seen the documents added in discover logs, but not showing in infrastructure metrics in the image I send.

Comment: Can you show one of the recent documents that has been ingested after your changes? Also did you make sure that the time picker was picking recent documents?